# Cross correlation of OFDM short preamble produces two peaks

Tags: cross-correlation, ofdm, preamble

I am trying to cross correlate the short preamble of an OFDM transmission. This is the preamble I am using:

```
0.046 # I
0.046 # Q
-0.132 # I
0.002 # Q
-0.013 # ...
-0.079 # ...
0.143
-0.013
0.092
0
0.143
-0.013
-0.013
-0.079
-0.132
0.002
0.046
0.046
0.002
-0.132
-0.079
-0.013
-0.013
0.143
0
0.092
-0.013
0.143
-0.079
-0.013
0.002
-0.132
```

However, if I correlate against real transmissions I captured, the correlation sometimes produces two peaks. This is a problem because I am measuring the distance between the peaks, which should always be 16 samples.
[image]

My question is: **How can I prevent such a behaviour?**

What is important to note is that I am not bound to follow the Wi-Fi standard. So it is, for example, possible to change the preamble itself or the correlation method (except auto correlation).

This is a minimal code example I use to create the correlation graph:

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np

sts = np.loadtxt('./sts.txt').view(complex)

def cross_correlation(transmission):
    correlation_result = []
    sts_conj = np.conj(sts, dtype=complex)

    while len(transmission) - 16:
        samples_16 = list(itertools.islice(transmission, 0, 16))
        correlation_result.append(abs(np.sum(sts_conj * samples_16)))
        transmission.popleft()

    return correlation_result # This can be plotted
```

So I basically multiply the complex conjugate of the known preamble samples with the received samples of the transmission and take the `abs` of the vector.

### Edit:

This is an image of a typical correlated transmission:
[image]
The magnitude of the peaks decreases due to AGC. But this is not an issue.

Comment: What is the sample delta between the two peaks? This is likely due to some sort of spatial diversity introduced by the transmitter. A trick you can use is to delay by the samples between those peaks and then integrate.

Comment: The delta is exactly two. The image above is an extreme case. In any case, I still don't see a peak at exactly one sample but two samples after that which are lower but still quite high. Could it also be echoes which are slightly delayed? They could explain the typically lower magnitude of the two other samples.